# Rotating a gradient based off device pitch, roll, and yaw - creating a hologram / security sticker effect

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a little fun addition into an app I'm working on, and can't seem to figure out how to get the animation to work completely / correctly.

At the moment I have something that looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/95O1Wul.mp4

#### What I'm trying to achieve

I'm trying to create a hologram like you would see on some [shiny game cards](https://youtu.be/tFuZfsCvsBM?t=138) or in [some bank notes](https://youtu.be/HgzFLjPpNtA?t=19) or on [those VOID stickers](https://youtu.be/colVXihqdGo?t=15).

I'm using the `x` position of the device to determine whether to shift the start and end point of the gradient. I'm trying to figure out in my head how to use these values to make the gradient's start and end points shift based on the values. And if I incorporated the other axes how it would move around if the device is rotated.

As for code, at the moment I have:

#### View Model

```swift
final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var gyroRotation = CMRotationRate()
  private let manager = CMMotionManager()
  private var timer: Timer?
 
  func startGyroscope() {
    if(manager.isGyroAvailable) {
      manager.gyroUpdateInterval = 1.0
      manager.startGyroUpdates()
      self.timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: (1.0/60.0), repeats: true, block: { timer in
        if let data = self.manager.gyroData {
          self.gyroRotation = data.rotationRate
        }
      })
      RunLoop.current.add(self.timer!, forMode: .default)
    }
  }

  func stopGyroscope() {
    if(self.timer != nil) {
      self.timer?.invalidate()
      self.timer = nil
      self.manager.stopGyroUpdates()
    }
  }
}
```

#### View

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var cm = ContentViewModel()
  var rotation: CMRotationRate { cm.gyroRotation }
  let gridItems = [
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40, maximum: 90)),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40, maximum: 90)),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40, maximum: 90)),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40, maximum: 90)),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40, maximum: 90))
  ]

  var body: some View {
    LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems, spacing: 30) {
      ForEach(0..<60) { _ in
        LinearGradient(
          colors: [.red, .orange, .yellow, .blue, .purple, .green],
          startPoint: rotation.x > 0 ? .leading : .trailing,
          endPoint: rotation.x > 0 ? .trailing : .leading
        )
        .animation(.linear, value: rotation.x)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .mask(
         Image("logo")
           .resizable()
           .scaledToFit()
           .opacity(0.3)
         )
       }
     }
     .padding(20)
     .onAppear { cm.startGyroscope() }
  }
}
```

Comment: In UIKit [`UIInterpolatingMotionEffect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinterpolatingmotioneffect) works great.  For SwiftUI, this might help: https://trailingclosure.com/device-motion-effect/

Comment: thanks @aheze that helped and triggered a thought!

Comment: I thought the idea was so interesting, I tried to implement it myself :) Feel free to check it out: https://github.com/eXCoreX/GyroPlay

Comment: @eXCore that's awesome! that looks more like the Apple Watch achievements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing on this to make it work, and I realised I didn't need the LinearGradient to animate but the Color itself:

#### View

```swift
struct CoreMotion: View {
    
    // -- where the data lives
    @ObservedObject var coreMotionVM = CoreMotionViewModel()
    
    let gridItems = [
        GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem()
    ]
    
    // -- the view
    var body: some View {
        
        LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems, spacing: 5) {
            ForEach( 0 ..< 60 ) { _ in

                coreMotionVM.tintColour
                    .animation(
                        .easeInOut,
                        value: coreMotionVM.roll
                    )
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .mask(
                        Image("logo")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .opacity(0.2)
                    )
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.top)
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel

```swift
final class CoreMotionViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    // -- what we share
    @Published var roll: Double = 0.0
    
    // -- core motion manager
    private var manager: CMMotionManager

    // -- initialisation
    init() {
        
        // -- create the instance
        self.manager = CMMotionManager()
        
        // -- how often to get the data
        self.manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1/60
        
        // -- start it on the main thread
        self.manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: .main) { motionData, error in
            
            // -- error lets get out of here
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            
            // -- update the data
            if let motionData = motionData {
                self.roll = motionData.attitude.roll
            }
        }
    }
    
    // cycle to the next point
    var tintColour: Color {
        switch roll {
            case ..<(-1.5):
                return .red
                
            case -1.5 ..< -1.0 :
                return .orange
                
            case -1.0 ..< -0.5 :
                return .yellow
                
            case -0.5 ..< 0.5 :
                return .green
                
            case 0.5 ..< 1.0 :
                return .blue
                
            case 1.0... :
                return .purple
                
            default:
                return .pink
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you getting the reward as well? In case you answered your question.

Comment: @swiftPunk only unless someone has a better, reusable, and cleaner approach. I'm not in it for the points, just helping others out

Comment: Why shouldn't he get the reward?  He posted a legit question and answered it in a way that's helpful to others.  That's why stack let's you answer your own questions.

Comment: You can even earn a badge this way: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner